# Нарисовать фигуру программно! так чтобы на нее наложились элементы RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Есть RelativeLayout с несколькими TextVeiw. Нужно так сделать чтобы фигура (прямоугольник для начала) была видна под всеми этими вьюшками. Доступ к фигуре нужен программный так как меняется цвет, размер фигуры, толщина рамки.
Как я понял одновременно нельзя использовать:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
setContentView(new DrawView(this));
```

в этом случае последний элемент полностью убирает первый.

Answer (score 1):

Присвойте `id` для `RelativeLayout` в `xml` и инициализируйте в коде.
После чего через метод `addView()` инициализированной вьюшки - добавляйте ваш прямоугольник, в частности `addView(0, view)` - через индекс `0` поставит на `"задний план"` добавляемую вьюшку.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но проблема в том что я не знаю как добавить прямоугольник без canvas или xml.

Comment: rlTableBody.addView(0, rect);

Comment: rlTableBody.addView(0, rect); не работает так как addVeiw cannot be applied to android.graphics.Rect